# Why is my ArrayList not looping through all values?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to make a small app that bounces balls around the frame of the window. When I add more than 1 ball to the list; it doesn't loop through them as expected.

Here's my code:

The Main Class:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();
private List<Ball> tempballs = new ArrayList<Ball>();
private static Timer t;

public void addBall(Ball b) {
    tempballs.add(b);
}

public void initUI() {
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

private BufferStrategy bs;
private Random r = new Random();
public void paint() {
    if (!tempballs.isEmpty()) {
        balls.addAll(tempballs);
        tempballs = new ArrayList<Ball>();
    }
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println(balls.size());
    for (Ball b : new ArrayList<Ball>(balls)) {
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);

        if ((bs = this.getBufferStrategy()) == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(2);
            return;
        }

        if (bs.contentsLost() || bs.contentsRestored()) {
            return;
        }
        if (b.y >= this.getHeight() - 100) {
            b.ydirection = -r.nextDouble() * 5;
        }
        if (b.y < 20) {
            b.ydirection = r.nextDouble() * 5;
        }
        if (b.x >= this.getWidth() - 100) {
            b.xdirection = -r.nextDouble() * 5;
        }
        if (b.x < 0) {
            b.xdirection = r.nextDouble() * 5;
        }

        b.x += b.xdirection;
        b.y += b.ydirection;

        if (b.xdirection > 0)
            b.xdirection += 0.1;
        else
            b.xdirection += -0.1;

        if (b.ydirection > 0)
            b.ydirection += 0.1;
        else
            b.ydirection += -0.1;

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.fillOval((int) b.x, (int) b.y, 100, 100);

        bs.show();

        g.dispose();

        bs.dispose();

    }
    i = 0;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        final Main m = new Main();
        m.addMouseListener(new Mouse(m));
        m.initUI();
        t = new Timer();
        TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                m.paint();
            }
        };
        t.schedule(tt, Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), 20);
    } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Here's the Ball class:

```
public class Ball {

private Random r = new Random();
public double y, x, ydirection, xdirection;
public Ball(int x, int y) {
    this.y = y;
    this.x = x;
    ydirection = r.nextGaussian() * 5;
    xdirection = r.nextGaussian() * 5;
}
```

}

and the mouse listener:

```
public class Mouse implements MouseListener {
Main m;
public Mouse(Main m) {
    this.m = m;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    m.addBall(new Ball(e.getX(), e.getY()));
    System.out.println("cl");

}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

}
```

}

Additional details:

- It only loops through the first item in the list, but the list size grows.
- I'm using java 6, but I will change versions if needed.

Comment: Why are you creating a new `ArrayList<Ball>` as a copy of `balls`? It shouldn't be causing the problem, but it's odd anyway.

Comment: Are you repainting? How do you check that the balls aren't being looped over?

Comment: this is exactly what debuggers are for... does nobody get taught how to debug anymore?

Comment: I'm making a new ArrayList<Ball> as a copy of balls to avoid ConcurrentModification exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your loop does not behave as intended, try to find out why it is cancelled. You have two `return` statements in your loop which could cause this behavior. Make sysouts before those returns to figure out which one is the cause. Then find out why your if around the return is true. To digg deeper you can use your IDE's debugging mode and place breakpoints at interesting lines or use the step mode to run one line of code at a time.

Besides this you can place both `if` before the loop, the values they are checking should not change while you are in the `paint()` function (you are using the UI thread which might change them).

Comment: I've taken your advice and moved all the graphics code outside the loop.It worked! I realized what i did wrong now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have below `return` statements inside the loop. If the execution reaches any of the `return` statements, the loop ends.

Figure out, if you are entering these conditions and returning for the first value in the list.

```
if ((bs = this.getBufferStrategy()) == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(2);
            return;
        }

        if (bs.contentsLost() || bs.contentsRestored()) {
            return;
        }
```